# elasticsearch nested query with ruby gem

Tags: ruby, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch ruby gem to connect to an es server and currently have an index with the below mapping. I am trying to understand the proper syntax to query these nested objects. Experimenting with queries such as the following, but keep getting errors. I was wondering if someone could get me started on the proper syntax for querying a structure such as this? thanks!

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log:true

client.search index: 'injuries', nested: { path: { week: {id: '1' } } }
```

Returns:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query
```

Sample Mapping:

```
{
  "injuries" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "tbd" : {
        "properties" : {
          "injuries" : {
             "properties" : {
               "timestamp" : {
                 "properties" : {
                   "__content__" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                   "timeZone" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "football" : {
        "properties" : {
          "injuries" : {
            "properties" : {
              "timestamp" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "__content__" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "timeZone" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "week" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "id" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                   "inactivePlayers" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "inactivePlayer" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "firstName" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "lastName" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "playerId" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "position" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "status" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "teamId" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "injuredPlayers" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "injuredPlayer" : {
                        "properties" : {
                          "displayName" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "firstName" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "gameStatus" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "injury" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "lastName" : {
                             "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "playerId" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "position" : {
                             "type" : "string"
                           },
                           "practiceStatus" : {
                             "type" : "string"
                          },
                          "teamId" : {
                             "type" : "string"
                           }
                        }
                      }
                   }
                  },
                  "season" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "seasonType" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) doesn't appear to have a `query` defined.  I think it should be something like:

```
"nested" : {
    "path" : "week",
    "query" : {
        "match" : {"week.id" : "1"}
     }
}
```